Get an error when used electron , fs, path modules in electron/react project
I have an electron+react project, get an error when I import fs or path modules into my react component file.
contextBridge in preload.js doesn't work too, get undefined when I use window.api in app.js.
app.js:
const { dialog } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');

Error

ERROR in ./src/App.js 16:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/lotso/Documents/workspace/my-app/src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 1:11-24
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:

add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


main.js:
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('node:path')
const url = require('url');
const mode = process.argv[2];

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1000,height: 800,darkTheme: true,fullscreenable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      preload: path.resolve(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      contextIsolation: false,
    }
  })

  // dev or production 
  if(mode === 'dev') { 
      mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000/")
  } else { 
      mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
          pathname:path.join(__dirname, './build/index.html'), 
          protocol:'file:', 
          slashes:true 
      }))
  }
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})

preload.js:
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
 
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
  openDialog: () => ipcRenderer.send('open-dialog'),
  receiveDialogPaths: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on('selected-files', (event, paths) => callback(paths))
});

Get some solution, but it doesn't work
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  // resolve fs or path module, 
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    fallback: {
      "fs": require.resolve('fs'),
      "path": require.resolve("path"),
      "electron": require.resolve('electron'),
    }
  },


I can't mark as duplicate, but same as -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/78161983/9718056
