using NPM to create React App: BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case
So for the past week or so I have been working on a project, a website for people who are fans of the band Gorillaz. I'm doing this project to fulfill the requirements of a Front End Engineering course that I am taking.
So Basically, so far the website is just very simple a couple of pages with React Routes leading to each one. I've got the routes working. Next, I made a page with API token data from ticketmaster.com that is going to show Tour dates for the band. That seems to just need a minor tweak, data.map is not a function etc etc. But however, the big problem that I am having relates to a NodeIRC based IRC chat room that I would like to implement for potential users to congregate to a chat room and discuss the music or whatever else etc. After I installed NodeIRC and tried to link it on the page, I was getting a complaint from my error log that said that I would need webpack to do what I'm trying to do, basically. Anyway, After I installed webpack, this is the error log that I get (I will also include my main App.js file, keep in mind it's a React based App).
ERROR in ./node_modules/chrome-trace-event/dist/trace-event.js 13:17-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/chrome-trace-event/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/MainFieldPlugin.js 8:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/util/path.js 8:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/util'
Did you mean './path'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, /home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js 1:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/legacy-streams.js 1:13-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/graceful-fs'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js 1:16-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/graceful-fs'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "constants": require.resolve("constants-browserify") }'
    - install 'constants-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "constants": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/base/BaseWorkerPool.js 8:39-54
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/jest-worker/build/base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js 26:15-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/jest-worker/build'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js 8:15-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js 15:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/NodeThreadsWorker.js 8:39-54
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/NodeThreadsWorker.js 15:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/NodeThreadsWorker.js 22:15-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'
ERROR in ./node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/messageParent.js 21:8-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers'
ERROR in ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js 5:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/loader-runner/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/merge-stream/index.js 5:4-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/merge-stream'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js 15:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/mime-types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/node-irc/lib/client.js 29:16-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/node-irc/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js 3:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js 4:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js 406:6-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'uglify-js' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js 484:14-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@swc/core' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/utils.js 567:18-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'esbuild' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js 9:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/watchpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js 13:15-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/watchpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/LinkResolver.js 7:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/watchpack/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/LinkResolver.js 8:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/watchpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/getWatcherManager.js 7:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/watchpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/reducePlan.js 7:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/watchpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchEventSource.js 7:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/watchpack/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchEventSource.js 8:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/watchpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/watchpack/lib/watchEventSource.js 13:15-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/watchpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/hot/lazy-compilation-node.js 18:47-63
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/hot'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/hot/lazy-compilation-node.js 18:66-81
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/hot'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js 11:19-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js 15:4-19
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js 13:20-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/TemplatedPathPlugin.js 12:4-19
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/asset/AssetGenerator.js 9:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib/asset'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/cli.js 8:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/config/browserslistTargetHandler.js 9:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib/config'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/config/defaults.js 8:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib/config'
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/config/defaults.js 9:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib/config'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/hmr/lazyCompilationBackend.js 30:27-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib/hmr'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/hmr/lazyCompilationBackend.js 30:46-61
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib/hmr'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptModulesPlugin.js 14:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vm' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "vm": require.resolve("vm-browserify") }'
    - install 'vm-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "vm": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js 18:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vm' in '/home/eliast/Documents/final reactapp project/gorillazfansite/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript'

And it just goes on and on like that
I will show the App.js file on my second post (the NodeIRC room is being implemented on another file, ForumsandIRC.js, which I can provide upon request):

I added NodeIRC package to my npm createreactapp build
Saw error related to the need to install webpack, so did so and imported webpack to my App.js and the other js page that is using the NodeIRC module. Added rudimentary setup code to the secondary file with the NodeIRC module.
See this long page of errors whenever I reach the 'homepage' of the app now.
Tried some solutions from another similar thread How to Polyfill node core modules in webpack 5 -- to no avail. 56 errors still present, all related to webpack


Please PM me for contents of App.js or ForumsandIRC.js if you need to see them.

Does this answer your question? How to Polyfill node core modules in webpack 5

I tried several of the solutions in the thread and still get 56 errors mostly all related to the webpack 5 polyfills issue.

for the record, I've only been coding for about 6 months. So I may have implemented webpack incorrectly. I'm not 100% sure.

I can't mark as duplicate, but it's the same problem as this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/78161983/9718056

@Arkellys I will take a look at that thread this weekend. Thank you so much. Like I say, I'm very new so sometimes I think I know what I'm doing but I don't.

It's okay. If it solves your problem, I would be happy to get an upvote for the answer so I can use it for duplicates in the future. This is a very common issue actually.

Hey so basically according to that answer, basically the problem is with the webpack.config.js file? If so, how do I rectify the problems with the config file? I'm not feeling any closer to understanding this, I'm sorry.

Okay, here's the deal. I left alone the webpack.config.js file and decided to do an npm i *package name* -S for all the packages that I was getting the error codes for. Now, I only get 20 errors, which is not nearly as bad but I still can't make the rest, all still mostly related to the webpack error code, go away yet.

@Emandudeguy The answer explains what's the problem and how to solve it. You don't need to install new packages or edit the webpack config. What are you not understanding? I can edit to add more details.

I'm not sure how to implement your solution because I'm not using any of the same modules you mention in your answer. Not using electron or Node.js. I've narrowed it down to 20 errors from 56, still just need to find the missing link because there's something I'm not getting here. I don't know how to preload because I've never done that, and not sure if that's what I need in my particular situation.

@Emandudeguy I feel stupid, I was sure you were using Electron! I mixed up my watching tags. So no, no preload or stuff like that. The reason of the error is still true however. I will write an answer for your case.

The error you get means that you try to compile Node.js code with webpack and that it is not configured for it. For a React app created with CRA, the Webpack target is set to the default value browserlist, as you can see on react-scripts config here. This target does not support Node.js core modules, as the error explains.
The library you want to use, node-irc, is a Node.js library, and you can't use Node.js on the browser side like React. If you want to use this library you need a Node.js backend. This is also explained on this issue by another user.

Thank you. I have a lot to learn. I will look at the node-irc and node.js documentation to see how I go about implementing it.
